# How to read individual values from JSON in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"eventData\":{\"eventDate\":\"Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM\",\"eventLocation\":{\"latitude\":43.93838383,\"longitude\":-3.46},\"text\":\"hkhkjh\",\"imageData\":\"\",\"imageFormat\":\"JPEG\",\"expirationTime\":1339538400000},\"type\":\"Culture\",\"title\":\"accIDENTE\"}";

NSData *jsonData1 = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *finalDictionary1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData1 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", finalDictionary1);

NSMutableArray *jsonParseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[finalDictionary1 objectForKey:@"latitude"]];
NSDictionary *res = [jsonParseArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@", res);
```

When I run this I get a bunch of errors. I want to get the value of latitude.

Comment: what errors your getting.

Answer (score 2):

Your `json` don't have `latitude` key. See below.

```
{
    eventData =     {
        eventDate = "Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM";
        eventLocation =         {
            latitude = "43.93838383";
            longitude = "-3.46";
        };
        expirationTime = 1339538400000;
        imageData = "";
        imageFormat = JPEG;
        text = hkhkjh;
    };
    title = accIDENTE;
    type = Culture;
}
```

=> New array with empty object.

```
NSMutableArray *jsonParseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[finalDictionary1 objectForKey:@"latitude"]];
```

and you try with none exist element.

```
NSDictionary *res = [jsonParseArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

See your `json`: `latitude` is not an array. And it's child element of `eventLocation`. Try to get `eventLocation` as `Dictionary` first then get `latitude` via `eventLocation`.

Hop this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the latitude from data.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"eventData\":{\"eventDate\":\"Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM\",\"eventLocation\":{\"latitude\":43.93838383,\"longitude\":-3.46},\"text\":\"hkhkjh\",\"imageData\":\"\",\"imageFormat\":\"JPEG\",\"expirationTime\":1339538400000},\"type\":\"Culture\",\"title\":\"accIDENTE\"}";
NSData *jsonData1 = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *finalDictionary1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData1 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", finalDictionary1);

NSString *latitute = finalDictionary1[@"eventData"][@"eventLocation"][@"latitude"];
NSLog(@"%@", latitute);
```

Although in a real world example were your JSON might come from a server, you will probably want to add error handling, indexing the data in multiple steps assuring the keys exists and values are of the expected type.

Comment: Thank you for the help stefan. It really helped me out to understand what is going inside.